# Conditional File movement in Spring Integration File Support

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am implementing one Spring Integration work flow as below.

```
IntegrationFlows.from("inputFileProcessorChannel")
                           .split(fileSplitterSpec, spec -> {})
                           .transform(lineItemTransformer)
                           .handle(httpRequestExecutingMessageHandler)
                           .transform(reportDataAggregator)
                           .aggregate(aggregatorSpec -> aggregatorSpec.requiresReply(false))
                           .channel("reportGeneratorChannel")
                           .get();
```

Now, once the above flow is completed, I need to move the `input file` to a archive directory. The decision to decide on the destination directory is based on a message header `processingFailed` and this header is added in `.transform(reportDataAggregator)` step in the flow. To move this files I have create another flow as in below code

```
 IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannels.direct("inputFileProcessorChannel"))
                           .routeToRecipients(routerSpec -> {
                               routerSpec.recipient("processedFileMoverChannel", createMessageSelector(Boolean.FALSE))
                                         .recipient("failedFileMoverChannel", createMessageSelector(Boolean.TRUE));
                           })

                           .get();
```

Selector method

```
 private MessageSelector createMessageSelector(Boolean ruleBoolean) {
    return message -> ruleBoolean.equals(message.getHeaders().get("processingFailed"));
}
```

Report Channel flow below

```
IntegrationFlows.from("reportGeneratorChannel")
                           .transform(executionReportTransformer)
                           .handle(reportWritingMessageHandlerSpec)
                           .get();
```

But, as expected with this flow, File movement is not done as the said header is not present into the flow execution.

So, How to achieve this goal to Execute the `file mover flow` after the report file is created?

Comment: You have two flows consuming from the `inputFileProcessorChannel` - if it is a `DirectChannel` they will get alternate messages (by default). What is consuming from `reportGeneratorChannel`?

Comment: Yes, thanks Gary, I see this issue with DirectChannel. Will change it. `reportGeneratorChannel` is terminal operation. No consumer after it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FileSplitter` populates for us this headers for each line to produce:

```
@Override
protected boolean willAddHeaders(Message<?> message) {
    Object payload = message.getPayload();
    return payload instanceof File || payload instanceof String;
}

@Override
protected void addHeaders(Message<?> message, Map<String, Object> headers) {
    File file = null;
    if (message.getPayload() instanceof File) {
        file = (File) message.getPayload();
    }
    else if (message.getPayload() instanceof String) {
        file = new File((String) message.getPayload());
    }
    if (file != null) {
        if (!headers.containsKey(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE)) {
            headers.put(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, file);
        }
        if (!headers.containsKey(FileHeaders.FILENAME)) {
            headers.put(FileHeaders.FILENAME, file.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

So, even if you done with an aggregation and ready to send a message into that `.channel("reportGeneratorChannel")`, you still have access to those file-related headers.

Making this `reportGeneratorChannel` as a `PublishSubscribeChannel` and move that "file mover flow" over there, would do the trick for you.

By the way: what you have so far with a `IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannels.direct("inputFileProcessorChannel"))` and a second flow on the same channel would lead you to round-robin dispatching. That's not pub-sub distribution. See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel

Comment: Making this `reportGeneratorChannel` as a `PublishSubscribeChannel` : After doing this `The Payload` passed to file mover flow will be the list from aggregator and it will try to copy this data only in the file? Is not it?

Comment: You can make a fist endpoint of that mover flow as a `transform()` to move your `File` from headers to the `payload`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Artem, Can I execute the `httpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` in async mode and let every thing else, as it is?

Comment: If you place an `ExecutorChannel` just after the `split()`, you would not need to worry about an async mode for HTTP: everything is going to be performed in parallel on their own threads. For async behavior you need to take a look into a WebFlux support: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/webflux.html#webflux